# Jquery element list concat by separator

Tags: jquery

I have a checkboxlist control and would like to get all the checkbox values that are checked concatenated into a string separated by '-'.
Is there any functions for this?
Ex:

```
$('#checkboxes input[type=checkbox]:checked').concat('-');
```

Answer (score 13):

I think your best bet is

```
$('#checkboxes input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
  return $(this).val();
}).get().join('-');
```

Basically, you're applying a function to each item that returns its value.  Then you assemble the result into a string.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311000/jquery-concatenate-values-from-two-elements). Perhaps using the `map()` function will work for you.

```
$('#checkboxes input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
  return $(this).val();
}).get().join('-');
```

Comment: Wow. I thought I was ahead of the curve on this one.

Comment: The fact all three answers are identical to the answer quoted here, down to exact formatting, means I upvoted this one, as it quoted the source.

Comment: Actually, the real source is the example on the jQuery documentation page for map(); I copied that and modified it.  (http://api.jquery.com/map/)

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to look at jQuery's [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) functionality (not tested):

```
$('#checkboxes input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('value');
}).get().join('-');
```

Answer (score 0):

That kind of depends on what you are trying to do. For example -

```
var list = ''
$('#checkboxes input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
    list += $(this).val() + '-'
});
```

Would give you a list with dash separated values but if you are looking to do this for form processing/submission, check into `.serialize()`

Comment: Actually, this would give you a list of dash separated values with an extra blank item at the end. like `item1-item2-item3-`